# Amazon web services paging through result set

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

I am looking through the [ItemLookupRequest](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/ItemLookup.html)

There is an option to use a tagpage to page through the result set, but in the [WSDL](http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl) there isnt a tagpage option. The problem I am having is **Itemlookup only returns 10 results. How can I page through the result set without out the tagpage option?**

thank you very much for your help

My goal is to pass an ISBN to amazon and receive ALL prices that book is being sold at. It looks like i can only receive 10 random prices. How can I get all the prices if they are limiting my return to 10 prices and not letting me do some form of pagination

Comment: This is somewhat of a side note, while you can only return 10 results you can make two requests at a time I believe, allowing a total of 20 results per call to the web service. It's been awhile, but I think the request object is an array, and you can do up to two. You might give it a try, it could speed up your process.

Answer (score 0):

According to the ItemId documentation you can only specify up to 10 unique ItemIds per request.  So it looks like they have a threshold per request of up to 10 Items returned per ItemLookupRequest request.  It's been awhile since I've used this API but when I was using it they were pushing hard that you cache product info except pricing as aggressively as possible.  This might be one of the ways they are forcing the client to cache through their API design.

ItemId
One or more (up to ten) positive integers that uniquely identify an item. The meaning of the number is specified by IdType. That is, if IdType is ASIN, the ItemId value is an ASIN. If ItemIdis an ASIN, a search index cannot be specified in the request.

Type: String

Default: None

Constraints: Must be a valid item ID. For more than one ID, use a comma-separated list of up to ten IDs.

Comment: My goal is to pass an ISBN to amazon and receive ALL prices that book is being sold at. It looks like i can only receive 10 random prices. How can I get all the prices if they are limiting my return to 10 prices and not letting me do some form of pagination

Answer (score 0):

The Amazon web service code can be a pain to navigate. In looking at the link you posted to [ItemLookupRequest](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/ItemLookup.html), have you tried this one (pulled from the request parameters)?

**RelatedItemPage**:    This optional parameter is only valid when the RelatedItems response group is used. Each ItemLookup request can return, at most, ten related items. The RelatedItemPage value specifies the set of ten related items to return. A value of 2, for example, returns the second set of ten related items

Comment: I understand the relatedItemPage is for items related to your Item NOT multiple copies of that item. Let me know if i read/interpeted it wrong thank you !

Comment: You are correct. It looks like I jumped the gun on this one. I did some digging on the web and was not able to find much. Have you tried posting on the AWS forums? I know there were a lot changes recently to the API that made many of these tasks much more difficult: https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=89335

I have a forum post out there and no response. Thank you for helping look into this!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ItemPage parameter to iterate through the pages of the ItemSearchResult, and use the "Sort" parameter to order the items (instead of them being "random"; which is actually the most "relevant").

Here's a snippit I've just thrown together, untested, and not something I've done before, but should work. You will need to do a lot more error handling than I've done here, and also cater for the maximum number of requests per second limit that AWS imposes on you:

```
    private List<Item> testAWS() {

        var s = new AWSECommerceServicePortTypeClient("AWSECommerceServicePortUK");
        s.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new AmazonSigningEndpointBehavior(AWSAccessKey, AWSSecureKeyID));

        var totalPages = 10; // Default value - changes on first iteration
        var books = new List<Item>();

        for(var i = 1; i < totalPages; i++) {
            var req = new ItemSearchRequest {
                SearchIndex = "Books",
                ItemPage = i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                Keywords = "Your ISBN", // There may be a better way to search for an ISBN - I haven't yet needed to
                Sort = "price", // Sort depends on which endpoint you are searching.
                Availability = ItemSearchRequestAvailability.Available, // Gets available products (mainly)
                ResponseGroup = new[] { "Small" } // Change for more details
            };

            var search = new ItemSearch {
                AWSAccessKeyId = AWSAccessKey,
                AssociateTag = AWSAssociateTag,
                Request = new[] { req }
            };

            var response = s.ItemSearch(search);
            // Store response in a list or something, which you can reorder as you want
            books.AddRange(response.Items[0].Item);

            totalPages = int.Parse(response.Items[0].TotalPages ?? "0");
        }

        // return your books, ordered by price ascending
        return books.OrderBy(b => b.Offers.Offer[0].OfferListing[0].Price.Amount).ToList();

    }
```

Comment: The itemSearch at most will return 9 results if the condition is set to all. if you specifiy a condition it will return 3 results of that condition. http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/ItemSearch.html
second paragraph

Comment: I've added the "ItemPage" parameter to the ItemSearchRequest object - the documentation states that this will retrieve page<n> of the results. This example calls the service once per page. I don't know if it works as I haven't tried it, but it was just a suggestion :)